# Multiple UPDATE, same column, different values, different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am trying to update a field with different conditions in where.
Actually I have the next instructions:

```
Update StmHistItm Set SHI_nPayable = @minPayable where SHI_iItemPK = @minrecno
Update StmHistItm Set SHI_nPayable = @maxPayable where SHI_iItemPK = @maxrecno
```

Is there a way to do this two instruction in just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression and combine the `where` clauses:

```
UPDATE StmHistItm 
SET    SHI_nPayable = CASE SHI_iItemPK 
                      WHEN @minrecno THEN @minPayable
                      WHEN @maxrecno THEN @maxPayable
                      END
WHERE  SHI_iItemPK IN (@minrecno, @maxrecno)
```